# SQL Server settings

Tags: java, sql-server, settings

I have a SQLServer database named : EventConsumerDB.

I have created Login, Password and User for this Login :

```
CREATE LOGIN EventConsumer WITH PASSWORD = 'EventConsumer', DEFAULT_DATABASE = EventConsumerDB;
CREATE USER EventConsumer FOR LOGIN EventConsumer;
```

Granted ROLE is : `db_accessadmin`

From Eclipse, I try to create the connection to this DataBase :

```
URL : jdbc:sqlserver://MyPC:1433;DATABASE_NAME=EventConsumerDB

Username : EventConsumer

Password : EventConsumer

Drive classname = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

The result is always the same :

[image]

It's the first time I install a SQL Server at home, it's quiet complicated...
Is there anything I've forgotten ?

Thanx by advance.

Comment: probably you need `check_expiration=off, check_policy=off`. New login may require change password at first login.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: [Connection-URL - Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample?view=sql-server-2017) ?

It shows you how to connect to an sql server via an URL:

```
public class ConnectURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a variable for the connection string.
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=<user>;password=<password>";

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); Statement stmt = con.createStatement();) {
            String SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Person.Contact";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("FirstName") + " " + rs.getString("LastName"));
            }
        }
        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @sophia-marie, thanx for your advice. Yes I've read this tutorial, but the solution was elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanx to those who've tried to help me.

The problem was the following : When I installed the product (Windows 10 platform), **Windows Authentication was the default authentication mode**.

Solution found on MS page : "[Change Server Authentication Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017)"

In the SSMS, right-click on the server name > properties > security.

Then in the "server authentication" block, replace Windows Authentication Mode by SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode.

Restart the server.

Note : don't forget to [activate the TCP-IP protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-2017) if needed. To turn it ON, you'll have to use the SQL Server Configuration console or PowerShell